# How to duplicate a document in MongoDB and increment a value in another field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to duplicate a document from my collection `orders` by filtering the field `cd_order` with value "**7650614875**".

Collection `orders` look like this:

```
{
...
  "cd_order": "7650614875"
...
}
```

I will copy this document more than 50 times (I will change this value in the query), so I also need to change the value from this field `cd_order` from this copied document to another value, so I though by converting into `int` and then use the function `inc` to increment 1 and then converting back to `string`.

I tried the query below but only the copy ocorrued, the rest didn't work:

```
var copy = db.orders.findOne({ cd_order: "7650614875" }, { _id: 0 });
for (var i = 0; i< 3; i++){     
    db.orders.insert(copy);
    { $convert: { input: $string, to: "int" } }
    { $inc: { "cd_order" : 1 } }
    { $convert: { input: $int, to: "string" } }
}
```

**How can I duplicate this document, increment 1 into field `cd_order` to not be the same as the previous one, and also to print all new `cd_order` at the end?**

Print example:

```
cd_order: 7650614875, 7650614876, 7650614877, 76506148758, ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to duplicate to convert the value and increment before duplicating the document, it worked well:

```
var copy = db.orders.findOne({ cd_order: "7650614877" }, { _id: 0 });
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    copy.cd_order = (parseInt(copy.cd_order) + 1).toString();
    db.orders.insert(copy);
}
```

I was also able to print all values using this query:

```
var orders = db.orders.find({ "nm_ancestor": {$eq: "Luigi D'arpino"} }, { "cd_order": 1 });
var ordersString = "";
orders.forEach(function(order) {
    if(ordersString.length>0) ordersString += ", ";
    ordersString += order.cd_order;
});
print("cd_order: " + ordersString);
```

Comment: It is a nice solution if you just need to duplicate a small amount of document as this fires one db call per document. You may consider wrapping it into [bulk operation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) to improve performance if you need to create large amount of documents.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$range` to generate an array of increment. `$unwind` the array to add to `cd_order` and `$merge` to insert/update into the collection

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "cd_order": "7650614875"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      inc: {
        "$range": [
          0,
          51,
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$inc"
  },
  {
    $set: {
      cd_order: {
        $toString: {
          $add: [
            {
              "$toLong": "$cd_order"
            },
            "$inc"
          ]
        }
      },
      "inc": "$$REMOVE",
      _id: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "cd_order",
      "whenMatched": "merge",
      "whenNotMatched": "insert"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cz8s1cThY8x)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am very very new to Mongo, should I place this code under `db.orders.insert(copy)`? Or does this code already copy this document as well?

Comment: I am getting this error `MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: E11000 duplicate key error collection: DEV.orders index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('63d30c86b1b50ee9f6ee5783') }`.

Comment: Sorry to bother, but now got another error: `MongoServerError: Cannot find index to verify that join fields will be unique`. I have a regular index that has the `UNIQUE` property for the field `cd_order`.

Comment: Yes! I created a index using this command `db.orders.createIndex( { "cd_order": 1 }, { unique: true } )`, it's already created.

Comment: thank you for your time and answer, I just found the answer and it worked very well! I updated my question with my answer.

Comment: @GuilhermeMatheus Would it be possible that the aggregation is not executed on the correct DB and collection? The issue is not reproducible on my end